# Is there a way to set a command in a plugin config so everyone can use it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

My friends and I share a Minecraft server, on it we have downloaded a plotworld plugin. If I `/de-op` myself it does not let me claim a plot, even when I have 0.

I was just wondering if there is a way to make a command that everyone can use by setting something in the config.

Comment: What plugin is it? Without that information, it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: PlotSquared for bukkit

Comment: Have you checked out [this](https://github.com/IntellectualSites/PlotSquared/wiki/Commands-and-Permissions) website? I have no experience with this particular plugin, but this website mentions permissions and commands

Comment: No, please only comment here and edit your question in that case.

Comment: Just to point it out, the very first permission in the link provided by D-Inventor is `plots.use` - "Allows user to use commands."  I have no knowledge of the plugin either but that sounds promising.  Though, that will not be something done in the plugin config file.  You would have to add it to permissions.yml.  Have a look at [this page](https://bukkit.org/threads/bukkit-guide-permissions.50305/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

When using Bukkit plugins, there is this concept called "permissions." Permissions basically just mean what players can use which commands. This is different than the normal vs operator permissions built into Minecraft. Almost every plugin (including PlotSquared) uses its own permissions.

Permissions look like this `plugin.command`, and can be given to certain sets of players using plugins like [PermissionsEx](https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/permissionsex), which help delegate permissions to players.

Although this is somewhat annoying, it is necessary to allow players to be able to use commands from plugins.